# Substitute the substitution

Tags: java, regex

How can we substitute the substitution? Here is an example to explain:

```
<h1>test test</h1>
<h2>sometext</h2>
```

I would like to replace this with:

```
<h1 id="test-test">test test</h1>
<h2 id="sometext">sometext</h2>
```

Note that the `id="test-test"` has a dash, which is replaced from a space character and `<h1>test test</h1>`, that is why the question is named "Substitue the substitution"

I understand that using multiple regex like `<(h[1-6])>(.*)<\\/\\1>` and then finding `h1 id="..."` and replacing would do the trick, but I want to do this in a single regex. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pattern.compile("<h1>(.*?)</h1>").matcher(s).replaceAll(mr ->
    "<h1 id=" + mr.group(1).replace(' ', '-') + "> " + ...);
```

Or

```
Pattern.compile("<h1>(.*?)</h1>").matcher(s).replaceAll(mr -> {
    return "<h1 id=" + mr.group(1).replace(' ', '-') + "> " + ...;
});
```

- That is, using the lambda version of [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) (since java 9).
- Replacing the shortest sequence `.*?` so `...<h1>...</h1>...<h1>...</h1>...` goes okay.
- `mr` is a `MatchResult`.

Comment: I am using Java 12 and there is no `Patter::replaceAll`, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html